# Password Encryption in Hikaricp

Tags: hikaricp

I am using HikariCP in a spring project. 
Right now, I defined a connection like this

```
<bean id="hikariConfigLegacyReasonCode" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="HikariCPReasonCodePool" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/>
    <property name="registerMbeans" value="true"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="15"/>
     <property name="idleTimeout" value="60000"/>
     <property name="connectionTimeout" value="5000" ></property>

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
             <prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://${LegacyReasonCodeIp}</prop>
             <prop key="user">${LegacyReasonCodeUsername}</prop>
             <prop key="password">${LegacyReasonCodePassword}</prop>
             <prop key="cachePrepStmts" >true</prop>
             <prop key="prepStmtCacheSize" >250</prop>
             <prop key="prepStmtCacheSqlLimit" >2048</prop>
             <prop key="useServerPrepStmts" >true</prop>    

        </props>
    </property>
```

Here, Server name , username and password will be loaded from a property file. Is there any way to store the DB password in the property file in encrypted manner ?

Comment: You can write your own factory extending `HikariJNDIFactory` and encrypting the password from the properties there, I did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the jasypt project.  It includes a number of integrations for Spring, including implementations of:

- PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
- PropertyOverrideConfigurer
- PreferencesPlaceholderConfigurer

http://www.jasypt.org/spring31.html

Comment: Thank you . i will definitely try this